# Difference in C# and C++ Byte array conversion for object

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to convert some C++ code to C# for an application. The function I am trying to convert calculates the Checksum of an object which comprises of MAC address among other details. The Checksum function in C++ is defined as :

```
unsigned short CalculateCheckSum(unsigned char* p, int n)
{
    unsigned short x, checksum = 0;

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        x = p[i];
        x <<= i % 8;
        checksum += x;
    }

    return checksum != 0 ? checksum : 51;
```

I have written the same function defined in C# is  :

```
 public static ushort CalculateCheckSum(byte[] p, int n)
        {
            ushort x, checksum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                x = p[i];
                x <<= i % 8;
                checksum += x;
            }

            return (ushort)(checksum != 0 ? checksum : 51);
        }
```

Here is the code that calculates the checksum in C++ :

```
    PCInfoClass pcInfo;
    char nicIDStr[1024];
    strcpy_s(nicIDStr, "34-29-8f-93-16-61");
    NICAddressStrToBinary(nicIDStr, pcInfo.nicID);
    char        outbuf[1000];
    pcInfo.timeStamp = 1234;
    pcInfo.expDate = 0;
    I32 pcInfoSz = 20;
    pcInfo.checksum = 0;
    unsigned char* byteStr;
    byteStr = (unsigned char*)&pcInfo;
    pcInfo.checksum = CalculateCheckSum(byteStr, pcInfoSz);
```

Since the *CalculateCheckSum* method, takes a Byte array as an argument, I have used the *BinaryFormatter* class which comes with System.Runtime. I have tried to replicate the same functionality in C# with the following lines :

```
            PCInfoClass pcInfo =  new PCInfoClass();
            char[] nicIDStr = new char[1024];
            string str = "34-29-8f-93-16-61";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                nicIDStr[i] = str[i];
            }
            NICAddressStrToBinary(nicIDStr, pcInfo.nicID);
            pcInfo.timeStamp = 1234;
            pcInfo.expDate = 0;
            int pcInfoSz = 20;
            pcInfo.checksum = 0;
            pcInfo.checksum = CalculateCheckSum(ObjectToByteArray1(pcInfo), pcInfoSz);



public static  byte[] ObjectToByteArray1(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Unfortunately the value of checksum comes out to be different for both approaches so the conversion is stuck at this point.

The other method used in this code is *NICAddressStrToBinary*, in C++ its defined as :

```
bool NICAddressStrToBinary(const char* nicIDStr, unsigned char* outbuf)
{
    int     c, i, dgt;

    if (nicIDStr == NULL) return false;

    //converted char to integer as ascii number.
    for (dgt = 0, i = 0; (c = nicIDStr[i]) != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        //if it is 45 '-' then the loop will continue;
        if (c == '-') continue;

         //if the ascii value is between 48 to 57 then we will decrrease with 48 of given integer
        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
        {
            c -= '0';
        }
        else
            if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f')
            {
                c -= 'a' - 10;
            }
            else
                if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')
                {
                    c -= 'A' - 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

        if (dgt >= 6 * 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (outbuf != NULL)
        {
            if ((dgt & 1) == 0)
            {
                //// it means c<<4 is c*2power4
                outbuf[dgt / 2] = c << 4;
            }
            else
            {
                outbuf[dgt / 2] |= c;
            }
        }

        dgt++;
    }


    if (dgt < 6  * 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In C# its been rewritten as :

```
 public static void NICAddressStrToBinary(char[] nicIDStr, byte[] outbuf)
        {
            int c, i, dgt;
            if (nicIDStr == null) return ;
            for (dgt = 0, i = 0; i<=nicIDStr.Length-1; ++i)
            {
                c = nicIDStr[i];
                if (c == '-') continue;
                if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
                {
                    c -= '0';
                }
                else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f')
                {
                    c -= 'a' - 10;
                }
                else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')
                {
                    c -= 'A' - 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }


                /* make sure there aren't too many digits
                 */
                if (dgt >= 6 * 2)
                {
                    return ;
                }

                /* accumulate the binary NIC ID
                 *  remembering that we're starting
                 *  with the most significant digits first
                 */
                if (outbuf != null)
                {
                    if ((dgt & 1) == 0)
                    {
                        //// it means c<<4 is c*2power4
                        outbuf[dgt / 2] = (byte)(c << 4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        outbuf[dgt / 2] |= (byte)c;

                    }
                }

                /* advance the digit index
                 */
                dgt++;
            }


            /* make sure I have enough digits
             */
            if (dgt < 6 * 2)
            {
                return ;
            }
            return ;
        }
```

Can someone please tell me what could be the cause of different values being calculated in C++ and C#?

Comment: That's a lot of code! It's great that you posted all the relevant code, but you could try to reduce the amount of code where the problem might lie (by testing smaller pieces for whether they work the same in both programs). Either you will find it out this way, or you will have a smaller question that is hence less intimidating to even start answering. Or is only the first snippet wrong?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the amount of code I dumped here! I didnt want to leave any details out but I do think the issue might with the conversion of the object to the byte array. In C++ the older code just does ```byteStr = (unsigned char*)&pcInfo;``` but in C# i used a library for the same. I am not sure how to make sure these are the same.

Comment: Unrelated; When you wind up with something like `i<=nicIDStr.Length-1;` save yourself and the compiler a bit of effort and rewrite it to `i<nicIDStr.Length;`. Saves people like me a bit of effort because when I see `<=` in a for loop exit condition, I start looking for the off-by-one bug it usually results in. This code fixes the off by one with the -1, but what if the length is zero? `i <= -1` could take a long, long while to become true if you get an unsigned underflow.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the CalculateCheckSum method, takes a Byte array as an argument, I have used the BinaryFormatter class which comes with System.Runtime.

That would have been a reasonable choice in isolation, but BinaryFormatter uses a complicated format that isn't "just the bytes of the object". Those bytes are probably in there somewhere, but a lot of other stuff is too. So in this case it doesn't work out.

Even in C# there are ways to get the raw bytes of a given object, but you would have to specifically design `PCInfoClass` for that purpose: make it a struct, use a `fixed`-size array for `nicID` (references are a no-go). Then you can use some tricks (which trick you can use depends on the version of .NET you're targeting) to get the raw bytes of that struct.

My recommendation would be to use a `BinaryWriter` to manually write each field to a `MemoryStream`, then use `ToArray` as you did. Be very careful to call the right overloads of `Write`, and explicitly write padding bytes as well. I cannot write that code for you without knowing what the class definition looked like in C++.